# Phonegap Contacts API - field names

Tags: cordova, contacts, field

Why is this sooooo difficult? All I want is a list of the field names in the Phonegap Contacts API. Not a big deal you would think, but it is - in fact, this is almost a generic problem with the Phonegap documentation: there's no details of the parameters that a method takes. The examples are not exhaustive which leaves users to go a-hunting elsewhere.

So I went to http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-contacts-api-20100121/#widl-ContactProperties-name and saw that the standard fields were name, nicknames, phones, emails and addresses. Hmmmm! Let's see if this workd then:

var fieldArray = new Array('name','displayName','phoneNumbers','addresses','emails');

for (i=0;i

for(j = 0; j < fieldArray.length; j++){

```
alert("Field Name: "+fieldArray[j]+"\n Data: "+contacts[i].name[0]+"\n Data: "+contacts[i].displayName);

alert("\n Name:  "+contacts[i].name[0]);
```

}

}

Not a chance. In particular, the second alert - contacts[i].name[0] - was the one I was most interested in. It simply returns "undefined". Tried this: contacts[i].name[0].value. Nada.

So question: what are the field names in a contact list and can someone with a contact in Phonegap ask them PLEASE to do something about the abysmal state of their documentation. I would volunteer, but I don't have the knowledge of Phonegap necessary to do the job justice.

Answer (score 1):

The app goes like this: I want to put all my contact details in an SQLite database for performance reasons and to allow me to manipulate the data more easily. So, I extract all of the contacts thus:

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();

options.filter=""; // Note empty filter will pick up all contacts

options.multiple = true;

var fields = ["*"]; // Picks up all fields

navigator.contacts.find(fields, findSuccess, onError, options);
```

I then stick it all in a database with selected field names: displayNmae, phoneNumbers, addresses, emails.What I'd really like to do though isiterate through all of the fields and stick the lot in a database with a routine like this in the findSuccess callback function:

```
var contactsArray=new Array();
var contactFieldsArray = new Array('displayName','firstName','lastName' ...);
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length;i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < contactFieldsArray.length; j++){
      if(contactFieldsArray[j].match(/(phoneNumbers)|(emails)/i){
         contactsArray,push(contacts[i].contactFieldsArray[j][0].value);
      }else{
          contactsArray.push(contacts[i].contactFieldsArray[j]);      
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, that needs some id of the fields available. It's got to be easier than if appears.

Answer (score 0):

First off you are looking at an old version of the W3C Contact spec. You'll want to look at this instead:

http://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/

As to your question as to what field names are in a Contact they are listed in the [docs under the Contact object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contact). If you are wondering about creating a contact don't use "new Contact()" instead use [navigator.contacts.create()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.create). Basically you pass an object literal to the method and it pulls the matching properties from your object and populates the contact.

I'm not sure how you go the array of contacts in your example but if you used [navigator.contacts.find()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find) you need to specify which [contact fields](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contactFields) should be returned by find. This is according to the W3C spec, I'm not in full agreement with it but we try to code to the spec.

Hopefully answers your question and if it doesn't just ping me and I'll do my best to answer.

Comment: Hey thanks Simon. The app goes like this: I want to put all my contact details in an SQLite datbase for performance reasons and to allow me to manipulate the data more easily. So, I extract all of the contacts thus: